# openMP read and write same shared array

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a problem with parallelizing below piece of code and I am even not sure if it can be parallelized (please let me know if it should be run in serial)

Here is my code:

```
 #pragma omp parallel for private(i) shared(arr,B)
 for (i = 1; i <= K; i++) {
  int s = B[i];
  if (i != s && (arr[s] ==0 || arr[s] != i))
      arr[s] = i;
}
```

in this code arr and B are shared arrays. also the elements of array B can be iterative this means that its elements can be in this order :

```
B = {1 ,2 ,1 ,2 ,3 ,3}
```

So each thread can write into the same location. And my main problem is in here. What should I do about this?

Comment: Can't see the point of the `if` - `arr[s]` will always equal `i` regardless

Comment: It is not always equal to i. I edited my code. First, the arr is 0 then it stores the values.

Comment: What is a typical size of `B` (`K`) and `arr`? Do you depend on the iteration order? Please describe more clearly what the code does and present a [mcve].

Comment: Size of B(K) can grow up to billions. The dependency here is that B[i] can have repeated values and for different indexes of i, s can repeat. For instance B[1] = 1 and B[25] = 1 so if thread 0 takes first 25 tasks and thread 1 takes next 25 tasks then thread 0 and thread 1 will read and write the same location in arr which is arr[1].